# Data type unexpectedly changed during MERGE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a temporary table into which 24K data records are imported with quotes (") around all of the fields and using a pipe (|) as the field delimiter.  I'm running a MERGE to UPDATE/INSERT data into another table and using the REPLACE to strip the quotes as it runs.  All of that works perfectly EXCEPT, ONE field seems to convert the data from text to scientific notation ("600E0" becomes 6.00E+02).  BOTH fields are nvarchar(20) in their respective tables and I would expect the quoted text to translate to unquoted text.

```
tmpEmployee.tmpCode = REPLACE(source.tmpCode, '"','')
```

I even tried changing the data type in both tables to char(8).  Still no joy!!!

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

```
MERGE tmpEmployee 
USING tempEmployees as source
ON source.tmpEmpNum = tmpEmployee.tmpEmpNum
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET
        tmpEmployee.tmpUserID = LOWER(REPLACE(source.tmpUserID, '"',''))
        , tmpEmployee.tmpLastName = dbo.properCase(REPLACE(source.tmpLastName, '"',''))
        , tmpEmployee.tmpFirstName = dbo.properCase(REPLACE(source.tmpFirstName, '"',''))
        , tmpEmployee.tmpEmail = LOWER(REPLACE(source.tmpEmail, '"',''))
        , tmpEmployee.tmpPhone = REPLACE(source.tmpPhone, '"','')
        , tmpEmployee.tmpCode = REPLACE(source.tmpCode, '"','')
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (tmpUserID, tmpLastName, tmpFirstName, tmpEmail, tmpPhone, tmpCode)
        VALUES (LOWER(REPLACE(source.tmpUserID, '"',''))
            , dbo.properCase(REPLACE(source.tmpLastName, '"',''))
            , dbo.properCase(REPLACE(source.tmpFirstName, '"',''))
            , LOWER(REPLACE(source.tmpEmail, '"',''))
            , REPLACE(source.tmpPhone, '"','')
            , REPLACE(source.tmpCode, '"','');
```

Comment: String operations should not do any numeric conversions.  I suspect more is going on -- for instance, how are you looking at the results?  If you are loading the data into Excel, perhaps it is converting the value.

Comment: `SELECT REPLACE('"600E0"','"','');` doesn't return `'6.00E+02'`, so we're definitely missing something here. I suspect we don't have the full SQL you're using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I'm "looking at the results" via SQL SELECT Query in SSMS.

Comment: @Larnu, you're looking at the entire SQL statement for that data field.  the only thing missing is the "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET" and a few of the other fields that are being updated.  ALL of them contain the "REPLACE" function and all the other fields copy without a problem.

Comment: *"you're looking at the entire SQL statement"* no, I'm not; `tmpEmployee.tmpCode = REPLACE(source.tmpCode, '"','')` won't run on it's one. There's no `FROM` or `UPDATE` or anything. Neither `tmpEmployee.tmpCode` or `source.tmpCode` have any context. Provide us with an [mre].

Comment: @RLoomas you should already know there is a [edit] feature. That SQL isn't readable in a comment. We also, however,won't be able to run it, so it does not provide an [mre]. We don't have access to your instance.

Comment: @Larnu code updated

Comment: Thanks, now we just need the rest of the [mre].

Comment: @Larnu, I'm not sure what's not reproducible?  I cannot provide the data because that is prohibited by company policy since this is employee data.
I left off any "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE" because I don't want the records deleted.  The MERGE runs without it.
So, this is a match-update or insert

Comment: We can't run your SQL, so it doesn't reproduce the problem. I'm not asking for *your* actual data, but you do need to supply sample data that when you use the above reproduces the problem. This is why I've linked you to what an [mre] in my last 4 comments.